# C++/CLI Could not load file or assembly "wrapper.dll"or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I'm going to be making a desktop application with WPF and will need to have C++ code. I've been trying to setup the C++/CLI thing. I have three projects, the CPP code, a wrapper for that code, and my c# project.

The problem I am having is that when I try to call a function in my C# project to my wrapper project, I get the error

> "Could not load file or assembly "wrapper.dll"or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found".

I can't find any solution to this. I've tried making sure that everything is running on x86, which is is.

Here is the code I am testing with

Project 1:

Logic.h

```
#pragma once
namespace MyApplication
{
    namespace Cpp
    {
        // This is our native implementation
        // It's marked with __declspec(dllexport) 
        // to be visible from outside the DLL boundaries
        class __declspec(dllexport) Logic
        {
        public:
            int Get() const;
        };
    }
}
```

Logic.c

```
#include "Logic.h"

int MyApplication::Cpp::Logic::Get() const
{
    return 42;
}
```

Project 2 (references 1):

Logic.h

```
#pragma once
namespace MyApplication
{
    namespace Cpp
    {
        class Logic; // This allows us to mention it in this header file

        namespace CLI
        {
            // Wrapper
            public ref class Logic
            {
            public:
                Logic();
                ~Logic();
                !Logic();
                int Get();
                void Destroy(); // Helper function
            private:
                // Pointer to the implementation
                Cpp::Logic* _impl;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Logic.cpp

```
#include "Logic.h"
#include "..\MyApplication.Cpp\Logic.h"

using namespace std;

MyApplication::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Logic()
    : _impl(new Cpp::Logic())
    // Allocate some memory for the native implementation
{
}

int MyApplication::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Get()
{
    return _impl->Get(); // Call native Get
}

void MyApplication::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Destroy()
{
    if (_impl != nullptr)
    {
        delete _impl;
        _impl = nullptr;
    }
}

MyApplication::Cpp::CLI::Logic::~Logic()
{
    Destroy(); // Clean-up any native resources 
}

MyApplication::Cpp::CLI::Logic::!Logic()
{
    Destroy(); // Clean-up any native resources 
}
```

Project 3 (references 2)
Main

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        using MyApplication.Cpp.CLI;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var wrapper = new Logic())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The answer is " + wrapper.Get());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assemblies for both Project1 and Project2 will need to be copied to the same folder as your .NET exe.  I suspect only Project2 is being copied

Comment: Not sure if this was the right solution but I changed project 1 (the c++ native code) to compile to a .lib and it worked fine. I didn't have to move any .dll's, which seems weird.

Comment: Well when you changed the first project to a lib, it is now _statically-linked_ to project2 meaning it is merged with the 2nd dll. There is one less dll and the remaining dll is being copied automatically by the build process due to your explicit reference to project2 by the .NET project.